# Cannot cast 'android.view.View' to 'com.example.shabeer.listview.ListView'

Tags: java, android, adapter, incompatibletypeerror

I get an error in this line here

`list_view = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_id);` shows error

> inconvertible type; cannot cast android.view.View to
>   com.example.shabeer.listview.ListView

also the `list_view.setAdapter(adapter);` is not working.

ListView class:

```
package com.example.shabeer.listview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class ListView extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static ListView list_view;
    private static String[] NAMES = new String[] { "Tom", "John", "Jack", "Pal"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
    }

    public void listView(){
         list_view = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_id);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.name_list, NAMES);
        list_view.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_list_view.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".ListView">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifect.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shabeer.listview" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ListView"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: did you import android.widget.ListView?

Comment: Like the Exception says, you cannot cast a `View` to your own `ListView` class, which has no relation to the `View` class. Either rename you class (which you should do anyway) and import the correct `ListView` class from android or use the full qualified name.

Comment: Change your class name like `MyListView` or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot cast an Android listview to your own listview.

Instead of "com.example.shabeer.listview.ListView" you need a "android.widget.ListView". This is the one you are referencing in your xml layout file.

```
public static android.widget.ListView list_view;
```

and

```
list_view = (android.widget.ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_id);
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your class name **"ListView"** to **"OtherName"**

```
public class ListView extends AppCompatActivity {
```

to

```
public class ListViewSample extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Comment: Saved the day, I had a Button class and the view won't cast to Button <thumbs up>

Answer (score 3):

Call `listView()` method inside `onCreate` then try, it should work.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
    listView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This would be the answer if your `ListView` were a `View`, but now I see that it's actually an `Activity`.  `ListView` is a very misleading name for an activity class!

Use the fully-qualified class name in your XML:

```
<com.example.shabeer.listview.ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Otherwise, it will assume you mean `android.widget.ListView`.